# Macbook won't power on

Tags: macbook

When I press the power button in my Macbook I do not hear the fan or the hard drive make any noise. The only thing that I have noticed is the light from the AC Adapter changes from orange to green for a couple of seconds then goes back to orange again.

I have tried several reset methods, with no avail.

Answer (score 3):

If its an older Macbook, try removing the battery and then try booting.  Sometimes a bum battery will prevent the machine from being able to boot.  If its a newer model, you obviously won't be able to try that.  If the battery thing works, just visit [apple.com/store](http://apple.com/store) and order a new battery.

Otherwise, if the machine is in warranty, call Apple or find an Apple store, you most likely need a new motherboard.  If its not in warranty, call Apple or find an Apple store, you most likely need a new Macbook.

Comment: One other thing worth trying if the battery is removable is a deep discharge; pull the battery AND the AC adapter and hold the power button down for a while.  Then reconnect AC and try to power it on...if the capacitors on the board are overcharged (say, from gradual static buildup) sometimes the board will refuse to POST, but doing this should help discharge them.  I've seen this revive tons of laptops, at least temporarily.

Comment: AAAAH, good point. I remember doing that to a laptop a couple of years ago after reading similar advice somewhere else.  Good tip.